# How do build tools work with deployment environments? Specifically dependency related

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, build, dependencies

For example with python pip and requirements.txt

I was trying to deploy to an aws image built from scratch, so i had to install python 3 myself and pip.

But from what I understand depending on what you deploy to such as heroku? it will automatically install your dependencies based off your requirements.txt??

I fail to understand how this works? How does heroku know to use pip and python? Wouldn't you have to remote in and install it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku uses [buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) to determine how to build your app. So, if you configure a python buildpack, it will look for requirements.txt.
Better still, often you don't need to explicitly configure a buildpack at all. Heroku tries to automatically detect the buildpack that fits your project, and if it finds a match, itr uses it by default. So, for a standard python app, you typically wouldn't need to configure a buildpack at all. Heroku would detect that your app is python, and would apply the necessary buildpack automatically.

This is just one trivial example of one of the (very many) differences between deploying an app on Heroku (which is a full-blown PAAS), as opposed to directly on AWS (which at a basic level is primarily IAAS). Heroku strives to make life simpler for you, although that comes, of course, at a cost.